# Memory allocation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, memory-management, data-structures

How can we implement a data structure that  allocate & tracks memory with the following constraints

1. Allocate and Free Memory in O(1)
2. Min fragmentation.

Lets say you have 1 KB unit of memory.
You need to allocate between 2kB - 64 KB memory

For eg

A- 1

B-1

C-4

D-2

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9     10

x   A   x   B   C   C   C   C   D   D     x

If we allocate memory at the min address available when we free (shown as x above) memory we will have fragmentation. So in above example even if 3units are free we cant allocate memory of 3 continuous units.

Comment: "min fragmentation" is not a constraint, but an optimization goal.

Comment: Yup - there it is, the heap memory management conundrum in a nutshell :) The only way to allocate that remaining 3K as one block is to relocate the already allocated blocks, and that means keeping track of the pointers that point to it.

Comment: Even if have a table which maintains list of pointers that refer to free space how can we get in O(1)  I am looking for ways of designing DS for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "buddy system" or "buddy memory allocation". That's probably the best solution you will find. Though, it is not purely O(1), it suffers from some internal fragmentation, and external fragmentation can also happen...

You can avoid internal fragmentation completely by using an augmented tree, but then operations take O(log N) time. And you still have external fragmentation.